# Encoding JSON with spaces in string in PHP from a PHP Session before passing it to Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, session, encode

I am encoding JSON with spaces in the string in PHP before passing it to Vue.js, however the process is failing. If I test without the spaces everything is fine.

I am sure there is a basic bit of theory than I am just not aware of but if someone could explain that would great.

The encoding code is below:

```
<?php $f = Session::get('foods');?>

<?php $a = json_encode($f); ?>
```

Passing to Vue

```
<credits f = {{$a}} a = {{$b}}  c={{$cr}}></credits>
```

Comment: How are you passing `$a` to `Vue.js`?

Comment: Through props, I have added that to above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the attributes if they can have spaces.

```
<credits f='{{$a}}' a='{{$b}}'  c='{{$cr}}'></credits>
```